# How to create a specific timeline? e.g (t, t+1, t+2, ....)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create an empty data frame with a specific timeline which looks like the one below.

```
Timeline 
.
.
t-2
t-1
t
t+1
t+2
.
.
```

Currently, I do not know any other way other than creating a dictionary and manually typing.

```py
timeline = {'Timeline': ['t-2','t-1','t','t+1','t+2']}
finaltimeline = pd.DataFrame(data=timeline)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `['t%+d' % i for i in range(-10, 10)]`?

Comment: is timeline a number or datetime type?

Comment: @Kapz see my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

For a specific range [-k, k], use this:

```
k = 5
finaltimeline = pd.DataFrame(data={'Timeline': ['t%+d' % i for i in range(-k, k)]})
```

Answer (score 0):

A very helpful function here is pandas `date_range` which is very flexible in how it can be specified.  Of the parameters `start`, `end`, `freq` and `periods` exactly 3 must be specified.

```
import pandas as pd

start = '2019-01-01'
frequency = 'd'
periods = 7

timeline = pd.DataFrame({}, index=pd.date_range(start=start, freq=frequency, periods=periods)
```

The resulting `timeline` is an empty dataframe (it has 7 rows but 0 columns) and is indexed by your date range.  You could also easily make the date range a column of your dataframe.